# Uploading a file to Google Drive via HTML form without JavaScript using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api

I would like to upload a file to `Google Drive` via plain `HTML` `form`, *without any JavaScript*, using `Google Apps Script`. I’m looking for a minimal example.

Here’s my current code, which isn’t working.

My `HTML` `form`:

```html
<form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/…/exec" method="post" target="response">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Upload a file</legend>
    <input type="file" name="file">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<iframe name="response"></iframe>
```

My `Google Apps Script` code:

```
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    var data = Utilities.base64Decode(e.parameters.data);
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(data, e.parameters.mimetype, e.parameters.filename);
    DriveApp.createFile(blob);
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Index").setXFrameOptionsMode(
      HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: In the current stage, when `multipart/form-data` is used for uploading a file with the form tag, it seems that Web Apps cannot retrieve or parse the request body of it, while the content length can be retrieved. And also, the file cannot be uploaded with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, while the file information can be sent. By this, a file uploaded using the form tag of HTML cannot be retrieved at Web Apps side. By the way, can I ask you about the reason that Javascript cannot be used for your situation?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for giving a comprehensive explanation. The entire website I’m currently building works without JavaScript, so I put it as a challenge for myself to make it 100% JavaScript-free.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I think that in the current stage, Web Apps cannot be used for achieving your goal. So, for example, how about putting a server for parsing the request body of `multipart/form-data` instead of Web Apps? The file is uploaded to Google Drive in the server. If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike I will probably use Firebase for file uploads then. Thanks again for your helpful replies.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your issue was resolved with it, I'm glad.